# Why does Dns.GetHostAddresses return HostNotFound but pinging the remote host has a response? (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dns, hostname

I have an application (C#) where I try to get the IP of a device based on its HostName and I do it as follows:

```c
public static IPAddress[] GetIPsByName(string hostName)
{
    try
    {
       // Check if the hostname is already an IPAddress
       IPAddress outIpAddress;
       if (IPAddress.TryParse(hostName, out outIpAddress) == true) return new IPAddress[] { outIpAddress };
      
       IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);

       if (addresslist == null || addresslist.Length == 0)   return new IPAddress[0];
  
       return addresslist.Where(o => o.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).ToArray();
   }
   catch (ArgumentNullException arNull)
   {
     return new IPAddress[0];
   }
   catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException arOut)
   {
      return new IPAddress[0];
   }
   catch(SocketException socEx)
   {
       return new IPAddress[0];
   }
   catch(ArgumentException arExp)
   {
       return new IPAddress[0];
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return new IPAddress[0];
   }
}
```

For some HostNames its IP is obtained correctly, but for others the SocketException exception occurs where the error is (SocketErrorCode = HostNotFound). (**Occurs by executing the line Dns.GetHostAddresses (hostName);**)

This problem would be normal if the device was disconnected from the network, but when performing a search with an IP scanner, the device is connected to the network (It shows its Hostname, its IP and its MAC address)

Any suggestions of what may be going on?

Comment: Does PING work with both IP address and Computer Name?

Comment: You are not comparing the same things, and ping is also a bad troubleshooting tool. `Dns.GetHostAddresses` will ask whatever recursive nameserver is configured for the name, through a DNS query and only that (so it can fail if your DNS setup is not right, etc.). `ping` or any other local tool will ask the OS to resolve the name. The OS can resolve a name in multiple ways, not only through the DNS. For example with `/etc/hosts` mapping or equivalent.

Comment: Are you sure the 'IP scanner' uses your hosts DNS server?

Comment: "The OS can resolve a name in multiple ways" And don't forget broadcast, especially in a Windows environment.

Comment: @jdweng For those devices that could not get the ip through the Dns.GetHostAddresses, ping only works with the IP address but with the HostName, my PC indicates that it cannot find the host with that name.

Comment: Remember also that an IP scanner will scan for *IP addresses* then attempt to reverse resolve those IP addresses. You are doing the reverse: trying to find a IP address for a given hostname. Sometimes you can do it one way round but not the other